# Spark parquet nested value flatten

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have parquet file. I loaded using Spark.And one of the value is nested key,value pairs. How do I flatten?

```
df.printSchema
root
|-- location: string (nullable = true)
|-- properties: string (nullable = true)


texas,{"key":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

thanks,

Comment: @G G if this answers your question, can you accept it? – Ashish 21 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#explode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag)) on your dataframe and pass it a function that reads the JSON column using scala4s. Scala4s has easy parsing API, for your case it will look like:

```scala
val list = for {
  JArray(keys) <- parse(json) \\ "key"
  json @ JObject(key) <- keys
  JField("key1", JString(key1)) <- key
  JField("key2", JString(key2)) <- key
} yield {
  Seq(key1, key2)
}
```

This flattens your dataframe.

If you also want to add column for key, you can use [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#withColumn(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) after explode(keep the key also in the new column).

Comment: @Alberto if this answers your question, can you accept it?